# Assigning a class to an object from within a function in R

Tags: r, function, class

I am trying to assign a class to an object from within a function with no success.

```
       a <- 1
       f <- function(x){class(x) <- "first"}
       f(a)
       class(a)
       [1] "numeric"
```

I do not understand why the assignment does not work.  Could you explain me why and tell me how to change the class of an object from within a function?  Thank you.

Comment: Hint: You need to assign to the proper environment.  Other hint:  This is not a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
a <- 1

f <- function(x){ structure(x, class = "first") }
b <- f(a)
class(b)
[1] "first"
```

As @Rich was hinting at in the comments, you had not defined a new object, so when you did `class(a)` it was just going back to your original definition of `a`, which was numeric (because you never redefined `a` to be `f(a)`).